How to Exclude Non-200 Status Code URLs Using Spatie SitemapGenerator in Laravel?
I'm using the Spatie SitemapGenerator in my Laravel application to generate a sitemap. I want to exclude URLs with status codes other than 200 from being added to the sitemap. I've already set ALLOW_REDIRECTS to false in my guzzle_options, but URLs with 302 status codes are still being included.
Here's the code I'm using:
config/sitemap.php
return [
    'guzzle_options' => [
        RequestOptions::COOKIES => true,
        RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        RequestOptions::TIMEOUT => 0,
        RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS => false,
    ],
    'execute_javascript' => false,
    'chrome_binary_path' => null,
    'crawl_profile' => Profile::class,
];

SitemapController.php
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;
use Spatie\Sitemap\Tags\Url;

SitemapGenerator::create(config('app.url'))
    ->hasCrawled(function (Url $url) {
        // Exclude URLs with query strings
        if (strpos($url->url, '?') !== false) {
            return;
        }

        // How can I check the status code here?
        return $url;
    })
    ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));

I tried using $url->getStatusCode(), but it's not working. How can I properly exclude URLs with non-200 status codes from my sitemap?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Updates:
I used the following workaround and it works now. Create a new request to check the status code. But the performance was very poor.
I have over 3000 URLs in my sitemap.xml. Takes less than 5 minutes before adding. It takes 17 minutes after adding. See if there is a better solution to this problem.
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$crawled_urls = [];

SitemapGenerator::create(config('app.url'))
->shouldCrawl(function (UriInterface $url) use($client, &$crawled_urls) {    
    if($url->getQuery() != ''){
        return false;
    }

    $endpoint = (string)$url;

    if(isset($crawled_urls[$endpoint])){
        return $crawled_urls[$endpoint];
    }

    $response = $client->head($endpoint, ['allow_redirects' => false]);
    $crawled_urls[$endpoint] = ($response->getStatusCode() == 200);
    return $crawled_urls[$endpoint];
})->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));

